# Why does interval operator in RxJava change the results from flatMap

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am running this code:

```
private void concatenatedSets() {
    Observable<String> concatenatedSets =
            Observable.just("1/5/8", "1/9/11/58/16/", "9/15/56/49/21");

    concatenatedSets.flatMap(s -> Observable.from(s.split("/")))
            .map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s))
            .interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                    tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(aLong));
                }
            });
}
```

The expected output would be

```
1
5
8
1
9
11
58
16
9
15
56
49
21
```

However, all I get is an endless session of counting from 1 to infinity as in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12...

I think the problem came after I added

```
.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interval()` is a factory method on `Observable` that gives you a sequence of values, starting from 0, periodically. It is a source operator that should be statically called like `Observable.interval()` but you called it on an instance. Most IDEs should warn you about invoking a static method on an instance because usually something different will happen than you expect.

I suspect you want to span out values separated by 200 ms; there is no standard operator for that in RxJava but is a common question here on SO (and should have an answer already).

Comment: So the IDE warned me about this indeed. However I've been working with RxJava for the first time, so I didn't know what do to about it. The biggest problem is that I had another use case where interval worked as intended (don't know why and how) which left me with the impression that I can use it to span out values like you said. Thank you. I will look for the answers to the question you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I normally use a trick combining the list of item to emit with interval using zip operator. Take a look of the code.

```
@Test
public void concatenatedSets() {
    Subscription subscription =
            Observable.just("1/5/8", "1/9/11/58/16/", "9/15/56/49/21")
                    .flatMap(s -> Observable.zip(Observable.from(s.split("/")), Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (i, t) -> i))
                    .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(System.out::println);
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
            .awaitTerminalEvent(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

This will delay every item emitted 200ms

You can see more practical example here https://github.com/politrons/reactive